# Is it possible to define or edit the ARN of an SNS platform application

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns

I'm currently creating an SNS platform application using Terraform. However the platform application that is created has an ARN that is not compatible with the company's naming policy because it has /app/GCM/ prepended to the application ARN. Is there a way of removing /app/GCM/ from the ARN in the Terraform script?

Comment: Why do you care what the ARN is? It's for unique identification of an AWS resource and is largely opaque. Surely you don't care about the instance Ids that are generated by AWS when you create an instance?

Comment: From the original post : 'an ARN that is not compatible with the company's naming policy'

Comment: You don't get to pick the ARN just like you don't get to pick the instance Id an instance gets. It's an internal reference that you can use across the ecosystem, mostly for things like IAM resource permissions. You shouldn't care about how it's defined in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARN is a unique identifier that has a format decided by AWS. It doesn't have anything to do with Terraform and you can not change it, that's just the way it is. If it conflicts with your company's naming policy you should change that policy to exclude identifiers that you don't control.